# How to add NSUserDefault data to a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have 3 UIVIewControllers that have NSUsuerDefaults to store data. My 4th UIViewController is used to display the total data collected between the first 3 UIViewControllers. How do I collect the data and display it in a UITextfield? Here is an example of my NSUserDefault code that I'm using: 
    [tex setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"storedTextValue1"]]; 
    [tex setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"storedTextValue22"]];
    [tex setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"storedTextValue43"]];             I want to add this collected data to a UITextfield on my 4th UIViewController.

Comment: Why can't you just concatenate all 3 in an NSString and use that NSString to set the text of the text field?

Comment: I'm switching in and out of all four UIViewControllers. I need the UITextfields on the 4 UIViewController to retrieve the data on the other 3 UIViewControllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use

```
tex setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"storedTextValue43"];
```

So basically you need to use `valueForKey:` in place of `objectForKey:`

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT**:

```
[text setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"storedTextValue43"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"storedTextValue1"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"storedTextValue22"]]];
```

**EDIT-2:**

UITextField(Total) is Say `txtTotal`

UITextField(storetext1) is say `txtStore1`

UITextField(storetext2) is say `txtStore2`

UITextField(storetext3) is say `txtStore3`

Now simply do this as

```
int sum = [txtStore1.text intValue] + [txtStore2.text intValue] + [txtStore3.text intValue]
txtTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@%d",sum];
```

Comment: How would I add the other two stortextvalue. I want the UITextField to show the total of the 3.

Comment: @TWcode: Check out the **EDIT** Section of my answer. I have modified my answer.

Comment: But how would you add all three storedtexvalue within 1 textfield?

Comment: @TWcode: _how do you add all three storedtextvalue within 1 textfield?_ . Here what does **add** stand for? I don't understand what exactly you mean when you say adding all three texts in 1 textfield. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Each storedtextvalue is saving a number value within a uitextfield(3 storedtextvalue). I have a UItextfield(total) that will represent a total of the 3 storedtextvalue. example: Uitextfield(total)= storetextvalue1 + storetextvalue2 + storedvalue3... how do i code this up. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @TWcode: Hope **EDIT-2** helps you. If you have any doubts then please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
textField.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"storedTextValue1"];
```

Or

```
NSString *storedValue1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  objectForKey:@"storedTextValue1"];
textField.text = storedValue1;
```

Comment: Looks good. But how would you add all three storedtexvalue within 1 textfield?